# SPARQL Tracker Could not run update, Property not found in the ontology

Tags: rdf, sparql

```
 tracker-sparql -qu "INSERT SILENT INTO <urn:uuid:38f> {  <urn:uuid:38f> a nfo:FileDataObject , nie:InformationElement ;nie:isStoredAs <urn:uuid:38f> ; nie:url 'file.mp3' ; nie:dataSource <urn:nepomuk:datasource:840494F4EDG> ;nie:deviceId '840494F4EDG';nmm:audioType 128 ; tracker:available true; a nmm:MusicPiece , nfo:Audio; nie:title 'Abandoner' .}"

  tracker-sparql -qu "INSERT {<urn:artist:38caadd1f13bf78a26aca0e7d42a8f58> a nmm:Artist ;nmm:artistName 'Aesop'; ?f nmm:performer <urn:artist:38caadd1f13bf78a26aca0e7d42a8f58>;  nmm:extEnsemble <urn:artist:38caadd1f13bf78a26aca0e7d42a8f58>  } WHERE { ?f nie:url 'file.mp3'}"
```

First insert returns Done.
Second insert returns Could not run update, Property 'urn:uuid:38f' not found in the ontology.

I really cannot understand how to link the new artist to an existing Music Piece.

Comment: What software are you using? MySQL? Does that speak SPARQL nowadays? What happens if you remove `SILENT INTO <urn:uuid:38f>` from the first query? I'd think it then inserts the triples in the default graph, just like you do in the second query.

Comment: I'm using tracker from GNOME. Tracker uses SPARQL. I've removed    SILENT INTO <urn:uuid:38f> and the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You second SPARQL INSERT statement is malformed:

```
INSERT {
    <urn:artist:38caadd1f13bf78a26aca0e7d42a8f58> 
        a nmm:Artist ;
        nmm:artistName 'Aesop'; 
        ?f nmm:performer <urn:artist:38caadd1f13bf78a26aca0e7d42a8f58>;  
        nmm:extEnsemble <urn:artist:38caadd1f13bf78a26aca0e7d42a8f58>  
} WHERE { ?f nie:url 'file.mp3'}
```

There is a `;` where a `.` should be to close a triple and start a new triple, which means `?f` has the position of the predicate in a triple. As `<urn:uuid:38f>` is defined as `nfo:FileDataObject`, `nie:InformationElement`, `nmm:MusicPiece` and `nfo:Audio`, but not `rdfs:Property` or OWL Property, Tracker signals that there is no Property identified by the URI `<urn:uuid38f>`.

The correct statement would be

```
INSERT {
    <urn:artist:38caadd1f13bf78a26aca0e7d42a8f58> 
        a nmm:Artist ;
        nmm:artistName 'Aesop' . 

    ?f nmm:performer <urn:artist:38caadd1f13bf78a26aca0e7d42a8f58>;  
        nmm:extEnsemble <urn:artist:38caadd1f13bf78a26aca0e7d42a8f58>  
} WHERE { ?f nie:url 'file.mp3'}
```